# Customize document-links on Alfresco Share

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

Am a new Alfresco developer an i was requested to customize and to add the feature of document-link in document library, i found out that the actions are called from `documentlibrary-actions-min.js`. In alfresco share the needed ftl and js files are `document-links.get.html.ftl`
and `document-links-min.js`. Could any one help me with calling this action, I already configured the the XML file but without any action to do.

thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I think you want to add a button in the `document-details` view in Alfresco Share, is that correct? The document-link though is already there, so what do you need exactly? And changing `documentlibrary-actions-min.js` is not the "best practice" in extending Alfresco functionalities. Also, you're talking about Alfresco 4.x here?

Comment: @Alch3mi5t I dont know if my question was not clear but all i want that is to create link for the file,i guess its the same procedure as creating a copy from the file but in this case is like a shortcut under another document.hope this explanation is usefull

Comment: if you want to link a document (aka node) into another folder then you're on the wrong road. You'll have to reuse the copy-move-dialog & create a app:folderlink